# C# Regex to replace entire function's contents

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a bit of trouble getting an expression to work to replace the entire contents of a function. For example

```
void function1 (void)
{
     Some junk here();
     Other Junk here
     {
         Blah blah blah
     }
}
```

I'd Like to replace the contents of this function with some predefined value ie

```
void function1 (void)
{
     Something else here
}
```

This is what I have currently however it doesn't seem to work. I was trying to capture the first part of the function and then the ending curly brace which is on a new line by itself. I'm pretty new to regular expressions so forgive me if it makes no sense

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(function1)*?(^}$))", Replace, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or how I should go about this differently?

Comment: Why not just make a new function with code that you want

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't seem to work?" Does it fail to match anything? Or does it match the wrong thing? Or is the replacement wrong? (I assume `Replace` is a string of some sort? Does it include back-references, or why are you capturing the function name and closing curly brace?)

Comment: You need X. You thought a “Regex to replace entire function's contents” would get you X, but it didn't. [We can't help until you tell us what X is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Don't use `RegexOptions.Multine`, use `RegexOptions.Singleline`. This will make it much more simple, since you don't have to worry about break lines.

Comment: I'm trying to automatically replace multiple functions that are automatically generated from a tool. It is tedious to have to replace them manually. My regex expression doesn't seem to produce any matches. Replace is just a string with the replacement I want.

Comment: You've told us [one Why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys). Next you need to tell us why you think you need to “automatically replace multiple functions that are automatically generated from a tool”. Hint: replacing autogenerated code is a really really bad idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
/function1(?:.|\n)*?^}/m
```

See http://regexr.com/3geoq.

I think the major issue with your regular expression was `(function1)*`, which matches the string `"function1"` zero or more times. Example matching strings are `""` and `"function1function1function1"`. You probably meant `(function1).*`, but unless things work differently in .NET's regular expression engine, the `.` won't match newlines. I used `(?:.|\n)` instead to include newlines. I also dropped the captures, since your response to my question about back references didn't seem to indicate you were actually using them.

You also had an extra right parenthesis in your regular expression that I would have expected to cause an error.

Full working C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace regex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = @"something up here
void anotherfunc(int x)
{

}

void function1 (void)
{
     Some junk here();
     Other Junk here
     {
         Blah blah blah
     }
}

int main()
{
}";

            var replacement = @"function1 (void)
    Something else here
}";

            Console.Out.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(text, @"function1(?:.|\n)*?^}", replacement, RegexOptions.Multiline));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
something up here
void anotherfunc(int x)
{

}

void function1 (void)
    Something else here
}

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: I got a downvote, but I'm not sure why. If the downvoter is here, an explanation for what could be improved would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks this worked well. I'm glad you explained it, it definitely helped. I'm not sure why I needed to remove the $ either but it wouldn't match with it there. Will the \n catch all new lines? It worked for me but I've read that in windows the newline is marked as \r\n instead of \n

Comment: I believe the `.` will safely match the `\r`, so `(?:.|\n)` should still cover everything.

Comment: I see that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.  Let me know if it works for you.

```
public static string Replace_Function_Contents(string old_function, string new_contents)
    {
        Regex function_match = new Regex(@"(\s){1,}?([\s\w]{1,})?(\s{1,})?\(.{1,}?\)(\s{1,}){");
        var match = function_match.Match(old_function);
        return old_function.Remove(match.Index + match.Length) + new_contents + "}";
    }
```

Comment: One caveat is that this takes an entire function as an input, and replaces its contents.  Not sure if that's exactly what you need.

Comment: My reading of the question was that the input is an entire file full of code, and they only want to replace a certain function. Also, could you explain your regular expression? I find it hard to follow, and isn't `{1,}` the same thing as `+`? I'm also not sure what the purpose of `{1,}?` is... I imagine that's just the same as `*`. There are also a lot of captures here, but I'm not sure why, since they don't seem to be used.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I do not know what the entire function will be initially and so I'm not sure how I would adopt this. I'm very new to regular expressions so would you mind explaining how your expression works? Thank you